# Reading string with escape characters

Tags: parsing, escaping, flex-lexer

I am building a Lexer. I have a problem in string literal with escape characters. This is my lex code.

```
string  L?\"(\\.|[^\\"])*\"
{string}    {
             int len;len = strlen(yytext);
             yylval.string = strdup(yytext + 1);
             yylval.string[len - 2] = 0;return MYSTRING;
            }
```

This is my Parser Code.

```
tname1="xxxx\"s";
print tname1;
```

When I print the string, It is printing like

> xxxx\"s

.

But I want the result as xxxx"s instead of xxxx\"s. Even It is not working for tab and newline characters also. How do I fix it ?

Comment: You'll have to scan through the string you've just read, and replace escape sequences with what they represent. What magic do you think might do that for you? By the way, `len = strlen(yytext)` is not necessary. `yyleng` is always the length of the token.

Answer (score 0):

(The best answer is in the comments by @rici. Copied here as answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comment) )

You'll have to scan through the string you've just read, and replace escape sequences with what they represent. What magic do you think might do that for you? By the way, len = strlen(yytext) is not necessary. yyleng is always the length of the token.